# Is there a way to obtain all rows/data from paginated json file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, api, pyspark

Edited:

Here are my steps:

```
url = "https://ted.europa.eu/api/v2.0/notices/search?&q=TD%3D%5B3%5D&reverseOrder=true&scope=3&sortField=PD"

# get data from url 
response = requests.get(url)

# return the json data, and read the output dict keys
data = response.json()
data
```

I have obtained a json file from an api as such:

> ```
> {'took': 205, 
>  total': 1703997,
> 'results': [{'AA': '1',
> 'AC': '2',
> 'BI': [],
> 'CY': 'MK',
> 'DI': '1046/2018',
> 'TY': '1'},
> {'AA': '6',
> 'AC': '1',
> 'BI': [],
> 'CY': 'RS',
> 'DI': 'CODE_OTHERS',
> 'TY': '1'},
> {'AA': '5',
> 'AC': '1',
> 'BI': [],
> 'CY': 'BE',
> 'DI': '1046/2018',
> 'TY': '1'},
> ...
> ```

```
#read the output dict keys
data.keys()
```

When I convert it to a pd df

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
```

> dict_keys(['took', 'total', 'results'])

```
# create dataframe from key of interest
df = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
df.head()
```

This returned the dataframe as expected...

```
# count number of rows
len(df.index)
```

> 1000

However, I expected a total of 1703997.

I'm still pondering how to fix this

Any idea on how I can do that?

Comment: Your API should be able to take the page number as parameter. In a while loop, store the 100 results of page `n` and increment `n` until the returned json is empty. (or loop `for n in range(result['total']//100)`)

Comment: Hi Tranbi, can you be more elaborate about the while loop? thanks

Comment: You should first describe how you get those data. Repeat the process with the next page until the result is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the page in your API request. Unfortunately, the API Doc [doesn't seem to be available](https://docs.ted.europa.eu/home/index.html) yet.
However according to this example on [Github](https://github.com/andreas-andersson/TED-api-tool/blob/4b937b4d3a004b2ce5a5b39e7fdd70b1dbf47303/ted.py#L62), you should be able to get any page with `pageNum=`.
You should be able to append all rows to `df` with the following:

```
url = "https://ted.europa.eu/api/v2.0/notices/search?&q=TD%3D%5B3%5D&reverseOrder=true&scope=3&sortField=PD"
response = requests.get(url)
data = response.json()
df = pd.DataFrame()
i = 1
while "results" in data.keys():
  df_page = pd.DataFrame(data["results"])
  # print(df_page.head()) # uncomment to see page #i as df
  df = df.append(df_page, ignore_index=True)
  i+=1
  response = requests.get(f'{url}&pageNum={i}')
  data = response.json()
```

It could take a while until all pages are read, so be patient ;-)

###### Edit:

In your example the code will loop 1700+ times before getting the response `{'errorCode': 400, 'message': "The requested page number doesn't exist."}`. I don't know if your memory/the server can handle that much.
You might want to split your results in several chunks...

Comment: Thanks. but did you manage to pull any data? I ran this for over many hours yesterday, nothing happened.

Comment: I edited my answer with more details (and changed the loop condition to avoid `KeyError`). Try with `while i < 5`, you should get the first 4000 results